# Complex Numbers and Transformations

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers, transformation, rotations

If a transformation t acts by rotating every point of the plane around the origin by $\pi/5$ clockwise and then proceeds to translate it by vector $v$ = $(1,2)$.

How do I describe this transformation by complex numbers? (Define the function t(z) so that the image of any point z is t(z) after this sequence of transformations.)

So do I go with... $t(z) = z + (1+2i)$?

Comment: Is the answer alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotation is multiplying by a root of unity and in this case, it is $e^{-i\pi/5}$. A translation is addition, in this case, it is $1+2i$.

So putting everything together, we have $T(z)=z\cdot e^{-i\pi/5} +(1+2i)$.

Comment: Um for the final answer, can you explain why the transfomation is z * e^ipi/5, instead of negative pi/5?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @JayC, so sorry I took so long. That was a typo. I'm sorry about it. Please accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered section.